# UI Bootstrap 2.5 can't get chevron to change based on open or closed accordion

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

Following the documentation somewhat closely, made a few changes. Can't get the chevron glyphicon to point upwards when the accordion is open. Last 10 or so rows in the code snippet is what I have been following:

http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#accordion

Anyway, this is what I have. Whether or not the accordion is open or closed it still just points down. Here is my HTML (I have no custom JS associated with it, just using what comes with the UI Boostrap library):

```
<uib-accordion close-others='oneAtATime=true'>
    <div class='detail-menu' uib-accordion-group is-open='false'>
        <uib-accordion-heading>
             Job Descriptions <i class='pull-right glyphicon' ng-class='{"glyphicon-chevron-up": status.open, "glyphicon-chevron-down": !status.open}'></i>
        </uib-accordion-heading>                
        <li>Test 1</li>
        <li>Test 2</li>
        <li>Test 3</li>
    </div>
</uib-accordion>
```

Not sure what I am overlooking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is with `is-open="false"`. The way you get to know whether accordion is open or not is by passing a `$scope` or controller variable to `is-open`. Here, you don't have a reference to that.

Hence, changing `is-open="status.open"` would get you a refernce to that, and you can then access it to show your favourite icons.

```
<uib-accordion close-others='oneAtATime'>
    <div class='detail-menu' uib-accordion-group is-open='status.open'>
        <uib-accordion-heading>
             Job Descriptions <i class='pull-right glyphicon' ng-class='{"glyphicon-chevron-up": status.open, "glyphicon-chevron-down": !status.open}'></i>
        </uib-accordion-heading>                
        <li>Test 1</li>
        <li>Test 2</li>
        <li>Test 3</li>
    </div>
</uib-accordion>
```

If you want to keep it `false` in the beginning, just initialize `status` without `open` or set it to false from the controller (see that in below plunker)

[**working plunker**](https://plnkr.co/edit/OnNWWacYfOoopzG6kdcZ?p=preview)